# [buildbot]: How can we get the current build link that was running

Tags: continuous-integration, buildbot

I am working with buildbot and i have configured factory build steps. My requirement is to access the link of build that it is running as part of build step. Is there any environment variable that buildbot sets implicitly ? So that i can access it easily in build steps? I was trying to get it via `build_url = os.environ.get('BUILD_URL')` but the value of `build_url` is `None`

In jenkins CI we have `$BUILD_URL` env variable that gives the job url. Same way do we have any such in buildbot ? Please help!

Comment: No such option exists in buildbot? please advice.